# PHP detecting a Open/Download dialog box

Tags: php, excel, forms

unfortunately this question may get closed but i hope some people answer it.

I have some PHP code that opens excel with some html data in it. This is the PHP:

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['datatodisplay'];
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Data.xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

echo $data;

?>
```

And this is the form:

```
<form class='noPrint' action='demo/saveToExcel.php' method='post' target='_blank'
onsubmit="$('#datatodisplay').val( $('<div>').append( $('#dataTable').eq(0).clone() ).html() )">
<input id='excel' type='image' src='img/file.png'>
<input type='hidden' id='datatodisplay' name='datatodisplay' />
</form>
```

Now, this code works great, but could someone explain from a PHP perspective how it does this, ie. i submit the form, it opens a new page temporarily, comes up with a download box, i hit open in Excel and then i'm sent back to the form page (but with Excel also open)

How does PHP know that i've actioned the download and to return to the form page?

Comment: You really don't know the answer? With reputation 2,593?

Comment: would i be asking if i did. Rep means nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. Your browser never left the form page in the first place, since the file was downloaded instead of shown in the browser.

Comment: But it brings up a new empty page for the dialog box to appear

Comment: @ben the form action is `"_blank"` aka new page

Comment: And the browser is detecting that the new blank page is followed by a download, and subsequently closes the unnecessary blank page.

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't know - all it's doing is serving an excel file. The clever bit is happening in the JavaScript happening on the `onsubmit` method of the form